# React: when user visits from other url - redirect him to right url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, redirect, mapping

for our detail pages we have the routes set up

```
/d/:id
```

the problem is, that many external pages have our old ids and links on their pages, like `/old/:id`

How can i redirect them to the right routes in our app? 
The problem is, that they ids the external pages are having, are not the ones, we use right now. But he have already an mapping array for these redirects.

So what is the best way to do this with react?
user comes from `/old/:id(:-slug) -> goto /d/:id` with new id.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using react-router?

Comment: yes. we are using react-router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more detailed, and imagining that your mapping array looks like the following:

```
var mapping_array = [{ old_id: 1, new_id: 2}, {old_id: 2, new_id: 3}]
```

you can try this:

```
var redirects = mapping_array.map(function(mapping) {
  return <Redirect from={'/d/' + mapping.old_id} to={'/d/' + mapping.new_id} />
});
```

and then where you define your routes add:

```
<Router>
     ... //existing routes and configuration
        {redirects}
</Router>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works :) now the only problem i have is, that sometimes the customers used the also /old/id-slug.. 
but I will find a way how to get rid of the slug

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Redirect` component within react-router as described in the documentation:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#redirect